# Ruby - inheriting from Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm pretty new to Ruby.
I need to extend `Array` and I need my class to represent bidimensional arrays.

I've done this:

```
class MyExtension < Array

    def initialize(n)
        super(n, Array.new(n, nil))
        self[0][0] = "hello"
    end

end
```

This looks theoretically right to me, but when I do:

```
p MyExtension.new(2)
```

I get

```
[["hello", nil], ["hello", nil]]
```

instead of the expected:

```
[["hello", nil], [nil, nil]]
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 10):

That is a common mistake a beginner often makes. If you do `super(n, Array.new(n, nil))`, then `Array.new(n, nil)` will be evaluated only once, giving that same array (same object id) for each row. Since all the rows would be repetition of the same array, modifying one row by `self[0][0] = "hello"` would change all the other rows.

Instead, do

```
class MyExtension < Array
  def initialize(n)
    super(n){Array.new(n, nil)}
    self[0][0] = "hello"
  end
end

MyExtension.new(2) # => [["hello", nil], [nil, nil]]
```